# Force template refresh ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, refresh

I'm using [I18n localization package](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) to take care of the switching language part of my app. It uses a global variable to set the language wanted and a json file to store the translations.

As the switching of a language is just a change in a global variable ember doesn't detect it and doesn't render the templates automatically. I forced it via an action in the application controller :

```
Extranet.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
{
    actions:
    {
        localToFr: function()
        {

            this.localisation('fr'); // this changes the global variable
            this.get('target.router').refresh(); // this is what refresh the template
        },
        localToEn: function()
        {
            this.localisation('en');
            this.get('target.router').refresh();
        }
    },
    localisation: function(lg)
    {
        I18n.locale = lg;
    }
})
```

I have two problems with that solution :
1) The application template isn't rerendered via my

```
this.get('target.router').refresh();
```

2) And my other problem, it doesn't work on templates which don't request a server access ( e.g. : the nest of routes 'authSession' )

```
Extranet.Router.map(function()
    {
        this.resource(
            'parkings', {path:'/'}, function ()
            {
                this.route('parking', {path:'/parking/:parking_id'});
                this.route('historique', {path:'/parking/:parking_id/historique'});
                this.route('sessAct', {path:'/parking/:parking_id/sessAct'});
                this.route('rapport', {path:'/parking/:parking_id/rapport'});
            }
        );
        this.resource(
            'authSession', function ()
            {
                this.route('login');
                this.route('logout');
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Do you have reason not to use https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n? I am going to implement translations myself so I am quite curious.

Comment: No, I don't. It's just that what I18n offered was enough for me ( I only use this [link](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/i18n.js) from the package btw as I don't use rails for my back end) and I was following a ( quite old but still functionnal ) tutorial from Robin Ward [link](http://eviltrout.com/2013/11/24/i18n-in-ember.html).

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue. I just went with [`View.rerender()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#method_rerender) on the main view, which was a form in my case.